# Badly aligned tikz objects and bad page-break in deluxetable

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, page-breaking, aastex

I am creating a table in latex, and I need to use a `deluxetable` environment. I use the package `tikz` to draw some circles in the table. The problem I am having is that I want to reposition those circles because it looks very odd, so I want the center of the circles to be aligned with the center of the text. But changing values for the position of the circle does nothing. Even crazy large values changes nothing.

Here is an example with just one row:

```
\begin{deluxetable}{lccc|lccc|lccc}
\tablewidth{1.0\textwidth}
\tabletypesize{\tabletextsize}
\tablehead{ \colhead{Species pair}  &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Scores}  & \colhead{Species pair}    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Scores}  & \colhead{Species pair}    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Scores}}
\startdata
HOC$^+$/C&  \tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (0.25) node[text=black] {\tiny 0.19}; 
\tikz\draw[orange,fill=orange] (0,0) circle (0.25) node[text=black] {\tiny 0.31}; 
\tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (0.25) node[text=black] {\tiny 0.23}; 
O/C$_3$H$_4$&  \tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (0.25) node[text=black] {\tiny 0.06};  
\tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (0.25) node[text=black] {\tiny 0.05};
\tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (0.25) node[text=black] {\tiny 0.06};
HCN/CH$_3$OH &  \tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (0.25) node[text=black] {\tiny 0.02};
\tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (0.25) node[text=black] {\tiny-0.01};
\tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (0.25) node[text=black] {\tiny -0.07};\\
\enddata
\end{deluxetable}
```

Also, for some reason the page-break doesn't work, so the table continues past the end of the page, as you can see in the picture below.

[image: Example picture from latex pdf]

Comment: Please make your code fragment into a compilable example (Minimal Working Example) as that will be much more use to people trying to help. To be honest, the text looks centred in your example image. So I don't really understand the question anyway.

Comment: I tried to update the latex example to show a full example of one row. What I want to have is that vertical centre of the text, should be aligned with the centre of the circles. Right now they are aligned such that bottom of the text line is aligned with the bottom of the circles. But the centres of the circles are above the top of the text. Does that explain things better?

Comment: add `[baseline={(0,0)}]` option to your `\tikz` commands.